# How to combinate characters in a string once?

Tags: haskell

I have searched on the internet for a while for this problem. I need to make a function in Haskell that makes from a input string all possible combinations without duplication.

Example:

```
combination "new"
```

Will give as output:

```
["new","nwe","enw","ewn","wne","wen"]
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: In mathematics, those are called "[permutations](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=permutations)".

Answer (score 10):

`Data.List` module has a `permutations` function which does exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I am a newbie with haskell!

Answer (score 7):

[Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle) is your best friend. A quick search for type `[a] -> [[a]]` gives permutations as the second result. It is always good to give hoogle a try if you are searching for a functions, as types in haskell have a lot of information about what a function is doing and a restricted type search is very likely to find the functionality which you are looking for. For example, the above type has only four functions in the hoogle's database with exact type match and along with the function name most of the time this information is enough to unambiguously infer the semantics of the function.